# OSGI bundles and multiple jvms

Tags: osgi

osgi (equinox 3.6) framework while loading bundle creates  bundle  meta files in specified bundle directory .  we are working on spawning multiple jvm's . Can we use  bundle folder where my previous jvm has created ?   I meant can we install all bundles once and use them for many applications?

Comment: Hi , i think you misunderstood ! let me explain what we are doing : there will be main jvm running all time and when requested spawns new jvm which installs and starts its bundles in it directory . when a new jvm is requested we are again repeating same process above . But to reduce time in loading bundles we tried to give same bundle location already installed to subsequent jvms . can we do this .. looks like its working and subsequent  osgi in jvm comes up fast if we do this and problem we might get ?

Comment: or to speed up bundle loading can we call bundle.start in parallel ? will it effect bundle Resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to work out what you're asking... but it sounds like you want to share the OSGi storage directory between multiple separate OSGi frameworks running in different JVMs. This is not possible.

Comment: Hi , i think you misunderstood !

Comment: Hi , i think you misunderstood ! let me explain what we are doing : there will be main jvm running all time and when requested spawns new jvm which installs and starts its bundles in it directory . when a new jvm is requested we are again repeating same process above . But to reduce time in loading bundles we tried to give same bundle location already installed to subsequent jvms . can we do this .. looks like its working and subsequent osgi in jvm comes up fast if we do this and problem we might get ?

Comment: or to speed up bundle loading can we call bundle.start in parallel ? will it effect bundle Resolution ?

Comment: Sure... you can reuse the same bundle directory across multiple runs of the JVM, so long as the JVMs do not run at the same time.

Comment: Yes you can start the bundles in parallel. No it won't affect bundle resolution, because resolution is a separate process from starting.

Answer (score 1):

a) Yes you can share the same location URL among frameworks
b) You cannot share the framework bundle storage area/bundle cache (org.osgi.framework.storage property)

You know there is a special reference: schema for OSGi frameworks? This allows you to install frameworks quicker. Just prefix a URL with reference: scheme.

reference:file://....